# alert() after jQuery.noConflict()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to fire an `alert()` after an `jQuery.noConflict()`? It is not working for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $JQ = jQuery.noConflict();

    // ...code working...

    alert('done');
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying the code between your noConflict call and the alert is working? If so then something in that part of the code that is causing some error and thus halting the execution of the rest of the script. Have you checked the console for errors? If you are not getting errors you will have to show more of the code

Comment: check the console and see if there's any error.